# How do enemies scale in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am considering buying Borderlands 2 today, but I've read in a few places that enemies don't scale properly. Some say that this only occurs on normal while others say otherwise. I just want to make sure that if I do get it - that the enemies will scale properly as I go along. So is it true or false that enemies don't scale properly?

Comment: Somewhat I think. I was not sure about DLC because I know that some DLC (I forget which) adds 10 or 11 levels or something along those lines so I figure that it has to modify the scaling of enemies somehow.

Comment: Enemies scale based on what area they're in, not based on your level. If there's a problem with the scaling, it has more to do with the order you do areas in than with the enemies themselves.

Comment: @Oblivious Sage so is it kind of like Pokemon (yes I know different games, but bare with me)? where different levels of Pokemon are in certain routes/areas?

Comment: See the question Yi Jiang's Evil Clone linked, but yes, until you meet certain conditions it's like Pokemon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Borderlands, enemies do scale *properly*.
Wherever enemies scale, it does not introduce problems or imbalances.

Player's health and gun damage (values easily inspected) increase by 13% per level. Other variables, like enemy damage and enemy health, scale accordingly - while I can't readily prove that it is 13% per level, it is definitely adequate.

Some areas of the game have enemies of fixed level, while other spawn enemies of levels *(player level + some constant)*.